# Normal user can't unmount if mounted by root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, removable-storage

I'm running a script that needs root privileges. One of its functionality is mounting an attached user HDD by using `udisksctl` utility. I'm using it like

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdX --options umask=0000
```

but when it succeed, it automaticaly mounts it to `/media/root/<LABEL>`. But since it mounts it in root's directory, a normal user can't use it or unmount it etc.

How can I succeed it? Anything wrong with my umask usage or it is about env variables? (My distro is Ubuntu, I'm using udisksctl for cross-platform issues.)

Comment: It's normal that users can't unmount what other users have mounted, doing otherwise would be a major security problem. What do you want to do? Authorize certain users to access and unmount this specific directory? Are there other mount points under `/media/root` that you'd want to protect? Why are you using `udisksctl` rather than calling `mount` directly?

Comment: `sudo -u <yourUser> <mountCommand>` might work?

Comment: My mount script is triggered via a root-privileged program.  I want to use udisksctl because there is cross-platform issues for `udisks` and `udisks2`. mount command always wants a target directory for mounting but `udisksctl` automatically mounts it under /media/<username>/<labelname>

Comment: if there is a `user` option in `/etc/fstab` I think a normal user can `umount` it, otherwise if you can mount in a directory you own then it may simplify things

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you can choose a mountpoint that is accessible. So try:

```
mount /dev/sdX /target/blablabla -o rw,umask=0000
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue. In `/media/X/<labelname>`, `X` comes from environment variable `LOGNAME`